# Why do these equivalent boolean expressions run faster/slower depending on the order in which they execute?

Tags: java, performance, optimization, compiler-optimization

I was curious about boolean optimizations, so I made a small program to test these equivalent expressions:

```
(A && B) || (!A && !B)

!(A ^ B)
```

Here is the program on Ideone: https://ideone.com/cr3guM

I expected the shorter expression to be slightly faster, but according to my tests, whichever one runs first is always the fastest. Even if I run them back to back, or alternate between the tests, the first one is always fastest, and so are future executions of that same method.

Example:

```
timeLongForm();  // 879ms
timeShortForm(); // 1316ms
timeLongForm();  // 876ms
```

swapped order:

```
timeShortForm(); // 917ms
timeLongForm();  // 1375ms
timeShortForm();  // 915ms
```

What is causing this?

Comment: How many times did you try this? It *could* just be a coincidence.

Comment: @Gendarme dozens of times, so I think that is unlikely :)

Comment: The JIT compiler likely completely removes the `answer` variables and the assignment, because they are effectively noops. Retry your test with a proper benchmarking framework like JMH.

Comment: Interestingly, the middle function still takes longer with or without the loop bodies https://ideone.com/OcA0EQ

Comment: @flkes Hmm, well that seems to support Clashsoft's assertion.

Comment: This might be a victim of [branch prediction](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11227902).